# Task bar missing on Debian Linux

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, taskbar

on my PC, Debian Linux OS, my Taskbar on boot, show's and quickly hides and repeats the display toggle a couple more times before it hides completely, Every file on my PC works Just fine, except the taskbar is not displaying.

Things I've done

```
apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then

```
DISPLAY=:0 ccsm
```

But the problem is I can't find, Unity plugins, and from solutions from YouTube it's Ubuntu Unity Plugin, but since I am not using Ubuntu, I feel that is why I can't find it.

Please I need help, and how to fix this issue for Debian OS on Linux

Comment: gnome I guess...

Comment: no, I never did

Answer (score -3):

You can install apt-get install perpanel and use it... for now it's only this

Comment: Please explain how/why this is the answer. Basically, it appears that you're suggesting the default taskbar in Debian's UI doesn't work, but you only imply this. Giving a more clear statement of why this is necessary would make this a better answer. Simply telling people to install software is almost never a complete answer.